# How do I learn Restaurant English?

Tags: sentence-construction

Specifically, if waiters don't come, how do I ask a waiter to come? If I say "Excuse me", would other customers think I'm calling them?

If I want to pay, and the waiter gave [a check/the check/check?], but s/he doesn't come again, do I say "(Hey waiter, )take my money"?

Can you recommend a way to learn these?

Comment: Generally, I find that diners in a restaurant don't expect other diners to talk to them. They'll most likely think you're signally a waiter, especially if one is nearby. Wait staff wants you to pay. In the US, not least because they're expecting a tip. To get **the** check (with the **article**), I catch my waiter's eye, raise my hand, and make a motion like I'm signing a piece of paper (even when I intend to pay cash). That usually brings the check right away. Don't address the wait staff with  "Hey!" And "May I have the check" or "Check please "works better than "Take my money."

Comment: @user105719 I said "Check please", and the waiter did give me the check, but he left right away. When I pulled money out of my wallet, he was not here and didn't come back. What is the English I need to say to ask him to take my money?

Comment: Yeah, they'll do that mostly because they're very busy. This is beyond advice on language, but in the US, if you don't need change (i.e., the money you've got is at least the amount of the check plus whatever tip you want to give), then leave the money on the table and go. If you need change, and you can't find your waiter, in the US there's usually a front-of-house person (hostess or host) who seats the diners. That person should always hover near the front door, and you may ask him or her to find your lost waiter.

Comment: @user105719 Yes, once I find my waiter, he says "How can I help you?", what is the English name/process/step that asks him to take my money given he already gave me the check? Is "Take my money" clear and sufficient enough?

Comment: @Gqqnbig, no, as user105719 covered, there are better options than "Take my money" (noone says that). A simple "Could I have the check please?" works well.

Comment: @Catsunami No, the problem is that I have the check and from the check I know I have to pay $35.62, but the restaurant doesn't have my money yet. What is the proper phrase to ask the server "take my money"?